# File not found load data infile mysql

Tags: mysql

I keep getting an error 29 that says file is not found with the following syntax and I cannot figure out why:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/rkartj2/Desktop/LOINCSUNQUESTV2.txt'
INTO TABLE xiao
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Table `xiao` has been created in MySQL 5.7 and `LOINCSUNQUESTV2.txt` was an Excel spreadsheet created on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not used version 5.7 of Mysql yet, the error you are receiving is the same in previous versions. `ERROR 29 (HY000): File 'C:/Users/rkartj2/Desktop/LOINCSUNQUESTV2.txt' not found`

This may seem a bit misleading to a newb especially since you can go to your Desktop and see that the LIONSUNQUESTV2.txt file is there.

I see one of two possibilities here which is either that Mysql does not have permissions to access the file from the current directory or that it does not know that the file is on your local server.

You can try using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. From [dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

If that does not work, you need to move file to a location that mysql has access to, such as the Mysql data directory.  In version 5.6 of a stock vanilla install it would be in this directory: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`. Try moving the file there.  I believe that Mysql looks at this location by default, so I would change `LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/rkartj2/Desktop/LOINCSUNQUESTV2.txt'` to `LOAD DATA INFILE 'LOINCSUNQUESTV2.txt'`

Comment: Version update - I'm actually using MySQLServer 5.6. I'm having a similar problem with another file, syntax below"

Comment: Version update - I'm actually using MySQLServer 5.6. I'm having a similar problem with another file, syntax is as follows: mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQLServer5.6/data/
    '> LOINC_v250.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE loincv250
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 ROWS;
ERROR 2 (HY000): File 'c:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQLServer5.6\data\
LOINC_v250.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Comment: BK435 I appreciate your response above and moved the file from the desktop to the data directory but I keep getting a file not found error.

Comment: I am giving you some leeway cause you are Newb...but ONCE AGAIN...look at the last line of my answer...n then look at your LOAD DATA command posted in the comment...